# Postman client not able to parse string response from JAX-RS response builder

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, postman

I am developing a jersey based REST application wherein i am using the response builder as below :

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
```

When executing this API in postman & when  it generates this error , i see something like this :

[image]

this comes only in the Pretty formatting mode. Is it a problem with Postman client or JAX-RS?

The Request header & the raw mode is shown below :

[image]

The "N" here is the first character of the message string. The Raw & Preview mode show the error message just fine.

Comment: can you show the request header as well as the response body?

Comment: What is the output of Raw and Preview?

Comment: added in the question...

Comment: could you able to provide your whole method?.and what was the consume type which you have set?

Comment: Postman inspect response header, if its `application/json`, it tries to pretty format it. In your case response is in plain text, hence postman fails to format it. I guess in JAX RS resource class you have something like @Produces("text/plain)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your API response type is application/json then Postman tries to parse it as JSON and fails to parse because it is simply an error message string.

To overcome that you need on server side return error in form of some JSON object.
Like this:

```
JsonObject error = ...;//some how created
error.addField("descr",e.getMessage());
return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(error).build();
```

Comment: I think its trying to parse it as JSON because my API response type is application/json. If you change your answer to say that, i will accept :). The one specified in postman is request type..

Now i wonder why is it sending string when i have said @produces to send JSON.

Comment: Reworded the answer