# @Produces({"application/json"}) not generating json

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Looks like JAX-RS uses standard providers to transform Rest API Response into the type specified in @Produces.

I have an API which works fine in successful cases(returns a JSON). In cases where i use response builder to generate response out of exception message(as below) , it does not come as a JSON, comes as a plain string. Why is the appropriate provider not throwing an exception or not writing it as a JSON?

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
```

Comment: You are sending a simple plain text string. What do you expect Jersey to do with it? Automatically format it to formatted JSON? How? It doesn't make sense what you want. If you want it to be a correct JSON format rather than just plain text string, then manually wrap the text in proper JSON object notation (with some String concatenation) or return a POJO as the error entity, and let the framework serialize it fro you.

Comment: I would instead have it return an error as it was not able to transform it into a JSON. Atleast the @Produces annotation would behave consistently then. Here it says it returns a JSON, but actually does not.

Secondly, thinking of it - why can't a String object be converted into JSON. I believe Jackson and other Serializers use reflection to get fields with values and wrap them up in the format. Why cant the same be done with string?

Comment: JSON is nothing more than String data. If you are returning a String, it is assumed there is nothing to serialize and the data sent as is. What else would you expect Jackson to do with a String?

Comment: I don't even know if Jackson touches it. Jersey has a String serializer, that might even take precedence over the JSON serializer. A string is so easy to write to the output stream, it doesn't need any special serializer.

Comment: This question stems from my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008142/postman-client-not-able-to-parse-string-response-from-jax-rs-response-builder where postman can't parse a string generated from a method similar to above.

Hence i think a plain string is not a valid JSON ; even as per JSONLint.

Regarding string serializer taking precedence , why should that happen. is that a feature?